# I'm a beginner in django and I'm trying to create a django project "portfolio" and I'm getting this error can someone help me

Tags: python, django

i have already done these steps

1. python -m venv ./venv
2. .\venv\Scripts\activate
3. pip install django
4. django-admin startproject portfolio
   and when i did
5. python manage.py startapp portfolio
   it shows this error

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio> python manage.py startapp portfolio
C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\portfolio\\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Hello friend  and welcome, could you please  make sure that manage.py exist in portfolio folder

Answer (score 0):

`django-admin startproject portfolio` creates a new directory, `portfolio`, in your current directory. `manage.py` lives in the new `portfolio` directory, so you'll need to `cd` into it before running startapp:

```
django-admin startproject portfolio
cd portfolio
python manage.py startapp portfolio
...
```